# How to move imageview from one layout to another layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

In my project there are two layouts .In the *first one*(above)in which i have  **3** `imageviews` of `largersize` and in the other(below) I had **3** `imageviews` same as above layout but of smaller size.

When I click the image in above layout the `image` should move to below layout where the respected image is present.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the onClick method (you can asigne to the imagen in the xml with android:onClick="nameofTheMethod" and the method must be public void nameOfTheMethod (View v) )
and in that method change the src of the image views.

myImgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagen);

If you want to resize the image android do this for you. You must to put a different resizen images in Drawable-hdpi ldpi and mdpi

Comment: how can  i show that image from above layout is moving from above to below layout

Comment: Ok ok  i dont understand you.

You must to use a animation. This theme is too extensive to comment here, its better you search in the android sdk examples and in the dev guide or here ofc